# Using DispatchQueue to fix Delay in updating NSTextView from switch statement

Tags: swift, multithreading, macos, grand-central-dispatch, nstextview

I am using a switch statement in Swift 3 (Xcode 8.3.2) to parse a range of JSON objects (using SwiftyJSON) for a macOS app.  For each case I am trying to print an update to a textView that is declared in the same class (NSViewController) and bound in the relevant storyboard using an @IBOutlet.

I have declared a function within the class to update the textView and call that function (`func addLogToConsoleWindow(newLogEntry: String) {}`) with the relevant text that I want to print to the textView.

The relevant code is:

```
    @IBOutlet var textViewActivityLog: NSTextView!  // Create an outlet for the activity log view
```

.............

```
        for jsonObj in arrayOfJSONObjects {
        if jsonObj != JSON.null {


            // Use a switch statement to select the correct Class to use for storing the appropriate event

            switch jsonObj["event"].string! {
            case "Docked":
                arrayOfDockedEvents.append(jsonObj)
                self.addLogToConsoleWindow(newLogEntry: "Docked event being parsed")
            case "FSDJump":
                arrayOfFSDJumpEvents.append(jsonObj)
                self.addLogToConsoleWindow(newLogEntry: "FSD Jump event being parsed")
            case "Progress":
                arrayOfProgressEvents.append(jsonObj)
                self.addLogToConsoleWindow(newLogEntry: "Commander's progress being parsed")
            case "Rank":
                arrayOfRankEvents.append(jsonObj)
                self.addLogToConsoleWindow(newLogEntry: "Rank information being parsed")
            case "LoadGame":
                arrayOfLoadGameEvents.append(jsonObj)
                self.addLogToConsoleWindow(newLogEntry: "Game load details being parsed")
            case "StartJump":
                arrayOfStartFSDJumps.append(jsonObj)
                self.addLogToConsoleWindow(newLogEntry: "Start FSD Jump event being parsed")
            case "MiningRefined":
                arrayOfMiningRefined.append(jsonObj)
                self.addLogToConsoleWindow(newLogEntry: "Mining event being parsed")
            default:
                if !setOfEventType.contains(jsonObj["event"].string!) {
                    self.addLogToConsoleWindow(newLogEntry: "\((jsonObj["event"].string!)) event discovered but not parsed")
                }
            }                
        } else {
            print("Haven't been able to find a jsonObj")
        }
    }  //  END OF 'for jsonObj'
```

...........

```
    @objc func addLogToConsoleWindow(newLogEntry: String) {
         textViewActivityLog.string? = "\n" + newLogEntry + (textViewActivityLog.string)!
         textViewActivityLog.scrollRangeToVisible(NSMakeRange(0, 0))
} // END OF addLogToConsoleWindow()
```

The behaviour that I am looking for is to have the textView (textViewActivityLog.string?) update immediately when the particular case is accessed.

However, the textView does not update immediately.  It only updates after the `for jsonObj in arrayOfJSONObjects {}` loop has completed which means upwards of several thousands of text lines appear at the same time rather than progressively as the for loop runs.

How can I get the textView to update at the point in the code that the `func addLogToConsoleWindow(newLogEntry: String) {}` function is called?

Any advice or guidance gratefully received.  I have been unable to find any relevant previous questions.

Comment: Parse the JSON on a background thread and update the text view on the main thread.

Comment: Thanks - that is beyond me.  So some research and I will report back.

Comment: I don't understand why the question has been marked down.  Can someone advise me why so I can learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested, I solved the behaviour issue that I was having after reading this response ([DispatchQueue.main.sync returning exc_bad_instruction Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40154653/dispatchqueue-main-sync-returning-exc-bad-instruction-swift-3]))

I made the following changes to the `addLogToConsoleWindow(newLogEntry: String) {}` function:

```
    func addLogToConsoleWindow(newLogEntry: String) {
    DispatchQueue.global().async (execute: {
        DispatchQueue.main.sync {
            self.textViewActivityLog.string? = "\n" + ":->  " + newLogEntry + (self.textViewActivityLog.string)!
            self.textViewActivityLog.scrollRangeToVisible(NSMakeRange(0, 0))
        }
    })
} // END OF addLogToConsoleWindow()
```

Which seems to have done the trick.

My thanks to those who have responded - your guidance towards multithreading was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As Willeke said, you can do something like that:

```
    switch jsonObj["event"].string! 
{
    case "Docked":
        arrayOfDockedEvents.append(jsonObj)
        self.addLogToConsoleWindow(newLogEntry: "Docked event being parsed")
    case "FSDJump":
        arrayOfFSDJumpEvents.append(jsonObj)
        self.addLogToConsoleWindow(newLogEntry: "FSD Jump event being parsed")

        //do on main thread...
        DispatchQueue.main.async
        {
            //updating text on label or other textview
        }

    case "Progress":
        arrayOfProgressEvents.append(jsonObj)
        self.addLogToConsoleWindow(newLogEntry: "Commander's progress being parsed")
    // ...
    default:
    if !setOfEventType.contains(jsonObj["event"].string!) 
    {
        self.addLogToConsoleWindow(newLogEntry: "\((jsonObj["event"].string!)) event discovered but not parsed")
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Edmund - that does not seems to have worked.  I encapsulated the self.addLogToConsoleWindow(newLogEntry: "Docked event being parsed") statement within the DispatchQueue.main.async and it hasn't made any difference to the behaviour

Comment: I will keep working on it and see if I can solve it first.  best way to learn.

Comment: I have sorted out an answer - please see the marked answer below.